# measure Ethernet speed python

Tags: windows, python-2.7, networking, ethernet, psutil

I am trying build Python module that will monitor and measure Ethernet speed (receive and send). This module is part of performance program.
I  looked for libraries that make it possible and the only library that i found is [Psutil](http://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#network) with the command:

```
psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True)
```

The output for this command is :

```
    'Ethernet 5': snetio(bytes_sent=211080874L, bytes_recv=929895370L, packets_sent=667031L, packets_recv=2757846L, errin=0L, errout=0L, dropin=0L, dropout=0L),
 'Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1': snetio(bytes_sent=0L, bytes_recv=0L, packets_sent=0L, packets_recv=0L, errin=0L, errout=0L, dropin=0L, dropout=0L),
 'isatap.replay.local': snetio(bytes_sent=0L, bytes_recv=0L, packets_sent=0L, packets_recv=0L, errin=0L, errout=0L, dropin=0L, dropout=0L)
```

So I got just bytes amount without knowing anything about time interval of the command measuring,so i can not extract from it the speed.

Which libraries are relevant to my task? how can i extract Ethernet speed with python script?
Is there maybe CMD command that simplify the task?

Answer (score 0):

By *speed*, you mean *bandwidth*. You can see the max theoretical BW with a simple ifconfig. To calculate the actual bandwidth in use you’ll need to call something like net_io_counters multiple times and use the output + time intervals to determine that. There’s no such thing as a “speed gauge”. A simpler but much less precise method could be to calculate the average used bandwidth since the system was started (assuming you didn’t do an ‘if down / up’ in between) by combining the output from net_io_counters and ‘uptime’.

Finally, to get an idea of your actual max bandwidth the common method is to download a file of a known size and time the download. Now of course, given how networks work, you will only get a clear picture here if the upload bandwidth of the remote file server is >= your local download bandwidth, otherwise the download speed will be capped by the remote machine/network.